# How to save query results dyanmically in number of Excel Workbooks and send them as attachments

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have the a query that creates a database table - `mytable` which looks like below-

```
Identifier Email          Column_A        Column_B 
  1        abc@abc.com     A1               B1
  1        abc@abc.com     A2               B2
  2        xyz@xyz.com     A3               B3
```

I want to export all rows with same identifier into same Excel Workbook, and send that workbook as attachment to the email address.For example in above case there will be 2 different workbooks containing rows with Identifier 1 and 2.

Number of rows in `mytable` vary every time I run the query and hence the number of identifiers.

I am aware that I can save query results by using an SSIS package but I think, in that case, all the rows of `mytable` will be saved in one Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but here's my theoretical solution:

Create a package-level variable for holding a "current" Identifier (Int32, I presume), and an Object-type variable for holding a resultset.

Start with an Execute SQL task to get a Distinct list of all the identifiers you are going to import, and use it to populate the Object-type variable.

Use a ForEach loop to iterate through the Object variable, and populate the Int32 variable with the current Identifier.

Inside the loop, put your dataflow that selects only the rows from the table with the current identifier (as stored in the Int32 variable), and imports to Excel.

In your Excel connection manager, use the Int32 variable to name the worksheet.

This should result in a final Excel file with a different worksheet for each identifier.   May need tweaking, since I haven't actually tested it though.